# How to trigger select change with Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

On a normal `select` tag I'm able to trigger a change event with jQuery using `$('select').val(2).change()`. This does not work with Materialize `select` tags.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
  
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    //$('select').val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1).change(); // Does not work
    
    $('select').val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1).formSelect();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="btn">Change</button>
</div>
```

I was able to make this work using `$('select').val(2).formSelect()` but I don't know if this is the correct way as this function is used to initialize the selects on Materialize and I haven't found documentation about it. Is this the "correct" way to achieve this or there are better solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the correct way, you will have to re-initialise the `select` element after changing its value

> If you want to update the items inside the select, just rerun the initialization code from above after editing the original select. Or you can destroy the material select with this function below, and create a new select altogether [Materializecss Docs](https://materializecss.com/forms.html#select)

```
var select = $('select');
// initialize
select.formSelect();

$('button').on('click', function() {
    // change
  select.val(2);
  // re-initialize material
  select.formSelect();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var select = $("select#TeamListId");

// initialize
select.formSelect();
console.log(select);
    
$(select).on("change", function(e) {
    teamNameId = $(this).val();
    console.log("\n\nteamNameId", teamNameId);
    myTable.search(teamNameId).draw();
});
```